# Store ContextMenu as variable with bound values

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'd like to store a `ContextMenu` in it's own variable like this:

```
@State var name = "Julia"

var contextM = ContextMenu {
    Button {
        print("...")
    } label: {
        name
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
RandomView()
    .contextMenu(contextM)
```

However, I'm getting this error: `Cannot use instance member 'name' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`, which makes sense.

If I try

```
func contextM() -> ContextMenu {
    ...
}
```

I get `Reference to generic type 'ContextMenu' requires arguments in <...>`

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewBuilder

```
@ViewBuilder
var menuItem: Button<Text> { 
    get { Button {} label: { Text(name) } }
}
```

and use it in the context menu closure

```
.contextMenu {
    menuItem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors were disguising the fact that your `Button` declaration was invalid. You need to use `Text(name)` as the label, or use a different `Button` initializor.

With that issue fixed, it works to declare a computed property like this:

```swift
var contextM: ContextMenu<Button<Text>> {
    ContextMenu {
        Button(name) {
            print("...")
        }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    Text("hello")
        .contextMenu(contextM)
}
```